# Sending HTTP requests after picking up a date, how to get the last value?

Tags: http, promise, observable, httprequest

Everytime I pick up a date (through datetimepicker), I wait 300ms with Observable-debounceTime if there is another input, and after that I send a http requests to get data from the server.

REQ 1: 2.10.2020 --> Response : 530 units --> needs 4 seconds on slow 3G internet.

REQ 2: 3.10.2020 --> Response : 12 units --> needs 1.2 seconds on slow 3G internet

It shows REQ 1 because it thinks it's the last request, but I wanna show "12 units" in that example.

I wanna show always the lastest request-response I get, but I have no idea how.
I tried with promises, but the problem I have there is that I can't set debounceTime. So I am using Observables now and I have this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: this.dataService.getData(date).pipe(takeLast (1).subscribe ( (response : Response) ={ this.response = response});

Comment: I am calling this many times in a row and I want the response from my last call...